# Can I create a storyboard from an existing Xamarin iOS app

Tags: ios, xamarin, storyboard, visual-studio-2017

I have just finished writing a Xamarin app, to run on Android, iOS and UWP. It is just a plain app, no view/controller stuff. It has been written in Windows using Visual Studio 2017.

Now I come to deploy it, I find there is a requirement from Apple for something called a storyboard.

I have found the storyboard editor, but do I really have to re-create my app again with the storyboard editor, or can I somehow capture the screens in my real app, and put them into the storyboard?

Comment: Do you wrote it using Xamarin.Forms?

Comment: Yes - some of the forms are xaml, and some generated from code.

Comment: if your app is working on Forms, you don't need to create a storyboard, you can submit your app as it is.

Comment: What storyboard? Do you mean [launch screen](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/application_fundamentals/working_with_images/launch-screens/) ?

Comment: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/deployment,_testing,_and_metrics/app_distribution/app-store-distribution/publishing_to_the_app_store/ says: Setting the Apps Icons and Launch Screens
For an iOS application to be accepted by Apple for inclusion in the App Store, it requires proper icons and launch screens for all of the iOS devices that it will be running on. App icons are added to your projects in an asset catalog, through an AppIcon image set in the Assets.xcassets file. Launch screens are added through a Storyboard.